# indexOf has a result of true when comparing two unique strings

Tags: javascript

I'm expecting this to return false, as the first string is "pass / fail" and the string that is passed into IndexOf is "Numerical Specification".

Am I not understanding how this function works? I thought it checks if string A is contained within string B?

[image: unexpected behavior]

Comment: The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Comment: It does exactly what you described, but you don't check the return value for -1, but just is it truthy, which -1 is. Also, code is text. Treat it as such. An image cannot be searched, or copied.

Comment: Jack -1 is truthy, in fact every non-zero value is truthy(positive or negative), 0 is the falsy :)

Comment: @AndrewLi `-1 == false` prints `false` in chrome console, `0==false` prints `true` :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably meant to use `"".contains`, which returns an up/down boolean instead of a match index:

```
"abc".includes("b"); // == true;
"abc".includes("x"); // == false;
```

since `-1` in js is "truthy", your `indexOf()` usage won't work as a conditional.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `String.prototype.includes()` rather that contains as contains is not defined.

Comment: @Gerrit0: stupid polluted stackoverflow "rightofthedot" "globals". (it ran here in the console) i always mix those method names up... fixed. stupid es commitee for naming something different than other web methods, and stupid me for not remembering. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

For example:

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome"); //output 13
```

Similiaryly:

```
var str = "Hello world";
    var n = str.indexOf("welcome"); //output -1
```

Comment: the missing part in this answer : -1 is a truthy value :)